# asking a person for a file to save in

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is to ask a user for a name of a file to make and then save some stuff in this file.

My portion of the program looks like this:

```
    if saving == 1:
        ask=raw_input("Type the name file: ")
        fileout=open(ask.csv,"w")
        fileout.write(output)
```

I want the format to be .csv, I tried different options but can't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is you need to pass `open()` a string. `ask` is a variable that contains a string, but we also want to append the other string `".csv"` to it to make it a filename. In python `+` is the concatenation operator for strings, so `ask+".csv"` means *the contents of ask, followed by .csv*. What you currently have is looking for the `csv` attribute of the `ask` variable, which will throw an error.

```
with open(ask+".csv", "w") as file:
    file.write(output)
```

You might also want to do a check first if the user has already typed the extension:

```
ask = ask if ask.endswith(".csv") else ask+".csv"
with open(ask, "w") as file:
        file.write(output)
```

Note my use of [the `with` statement](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) when opening files. It's good practice as it's more readable and ensures the file is closed properly, even on exceptions.

I am also using the python [ternary operator](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) here to do a simple variable assignment based on a condition (setting ask to itself if it already ends in `".csv"`, otherwise concatenating it).

Also, this is presuming your output is already suitable for a CSV file, the extension alone won't make it CSV. When dealing with CSV data in general, you probably want to check out [the csv module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `ask+'.csv'` to concatenate the required extension on to the end of the user input.

However, simply naming the file with a `.csv` extension is not enough to make it a comma-separated file. You need to format the output. Use [`csvwriter`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) to do that. The python documentation has some [simple examples](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#examples) on how to do this.

I advise you not to attempt to generate the formatted comma-separated output yourself. That's a surprisingly hard task and utterly pointless in the presence of the built-in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `ask` is gonna be of type `string` after the `raw_input`. 
So, if you want to append the extension .csv to it, you should do:

```
fileout = open(ask + ".csv", "w")
```

That should work.